# ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous on creation of new column

Tags: python, pandas

Using `assign` in Pandas 1.0 I would like to create a new flag column based on the following logic:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'val': [10, 2, 0, 1, 0.4, 2]})
df = df.assign(
    flag=lambda x: False if np.bool(x['val'] == 0) else True if np.bool(x['val'] < 0.5) else False
)
```

I expect:

```
df
   val    flag
0   10    False
1    2    False
2    0    False
3    1    False
4    0.4  True
5    2    False
```

Instead I get:

```
ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all()
```

I tried with np.where(), np.any(), np.all() but I do not get the expected result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Chain condition by `&` for bitwise AND:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'val': [10, 2, 0, 1, 0.4, 2]})

df = df.assign(flag= (df['val'] < 0.5) & (df['val'] != 0))
```

If `val` is count by some chained method is necessary lambda:

```
df = df.assign(flag=lambda x: (x['val'] < 0.5) & (x['val'] != 0))
print (df)
    val   flag
0  10.0  False
1   2.0  False
2   0.0  False
3   1.0  False
4   0.4   True
5   2.0  False
```

Comment: I think the `lambda` can be skipped; `df['val'] < 0.5` should suffice.

Comment: @HenryYik - Yes, it depends of chaing.

Comment: @HenryYik I corrected my output, which should be `False` when val=0. I don't understand why I cannot specify a more complex conditional statement in the lambda without getting that error.